# Binding a Swing JList into an array

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I want to bind a JList in a JScrollPane to an array , whenever the array changes the List changes .

Comment: @Ahmed, when you click "Insert`", you want your queue(`JList` in a `JScrollPane`?) to add an item and the `JTextField` will update to display the size of the queue?

Comment: No , When I press insert I will display the contents of queue in the Pane .
the text field is another input

Comment: @Ahmed, what are the "contents" of the queue and where's their source? I suppose I'm still a little confused, at least by the image. what part, if any, does the text field play in all this?

Comment: Hmm , Sorry for the confusion . Let me just put it this way .
I have a JList.
And I have an array which is updated as long as the program is going.
I want to make something like table.setModel(blabla) but for the list to be updated whenever this frame is updated

Comment: I changed the question totally

Comment: real arrays (`Something[]`) are not listenable in Java. I would advise you to use a `List<Something>` implementation. You should definitely take a look at **GlazedLists** open source library.

Answer (score 1):

The first idea, of course, would by to use one of `JList`'s constructors and hope that the `JList` component is updated synchronously with the array:

```
public JList(Object[] listData);
public JList(Vector<?> listData);
```

Obviously, this does not work out. Only, if you use the third non-default constructor

```
public JList(ListModel model);
```

and use the default implementation `DefaultListModel` and update its elements directly by e.g.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
...
model.setElementAt(value, 25);
```

you receive a dynamically updated `JList` component, by updating the `DefaultListModel`.

What Java SE provides is a "fixed-size List backed up the specified array" by the `java.util.Arrays.asList(T... a)` method, compare [Java SE API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

However, here the support of **Java SE** breaks. There is no `ListModel` implementation that is "backed-up by a List".

I have tried both ways to overcome this:

1. implement the `List` interface in a class synchronously updating an
   underlying `DefaultListModel`
2. extend `DefaultListModel`, synchronously updating an underlying `List` instance.

Neither way worked.

Therefore, I venture to say that **Java SE does not support this feature yet**. You have to code your own implementation of `JList` synchronized by a `List` instance or wait until a new Java distribution comes along, which features `JList's` or `DefaultListModel's`  backed up by `List` instances.